# Proper way to dispose Hwnd IntPtr

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, handle

I'm trying to figure out whether the following situation produces a memory leak or not.

I am getting a window handle from a WebBrowser control (there is a reason for this)

```
IntPtr p = webBrowser1.FindForm().Handle;
```

Later, I am releasing that handle in an overridden dispose method

```
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        hwnd = IntPtr.Zero;
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

Is there something evil behind my `Dispose` method that might cause a memory leak?

This might be pretty obvious to some, but I am hunting memory leaks so I'm trying to verify every line of code.

Comment: I think, your code is only setting your local copy of the handle of the main window (containing your webbrowser-control) to zero. That will not dispose the wbc. Disposing your form should work well.

Comment: The browser is not needed to be disposed here. It's done when the form is disposed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no significance in setting your HWND to IntPtr.Zero.

IntPtr is a value type, so having the value in that variable has no effect on anything. It does not keep any object alive. It's just a number that you are setting to 0.

If you got the HWND from an existing window, then no handle should have been duplicated and you don't have to release it. The HWND will be destroy when the form is closed.